# Finding smallest prime factor in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

Write a Bash shell script factor.sh that will do the following: 1) it prompts a user to enter an integer n from 10 to 100; 2) Find the smallest (prime) factor for that number, so if the number is 21, it would output the message “The smallest factor is 3”. If the number was 77, it would output “The smallest factor is 7”. 3) If the number has no factors other than itself, it should output “This number is prime”.

And this is the code that I have so far, but I keep getting an error.

```
echo "Enter a number from 10 to 100: "
read num
if (($num >= 10 && $num <= 100 ));
        then
                for ((i = 2; i <= $num; i++));do
                        if (($num % $i == 0));
                                then
                                        prime = $i
                                        break
                        fi
                done
                if (($prime == $num));
                        then
                                echo "This number is prime."
                else
                        echo "The smallest prime fatcor is: "
                        echo $prime
                fi
fi
```

The error that I am getting is "line 16: =: command not found" for `prime = $i`

And " line 20: ((: == 77: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 77")" where 77 would be the number I entered and is on line `if (($prime == $num));`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, in shell, spaces matter.  Replace `prime = $i` with `prime=$i`.

Comment: Second, Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: @John1024 Great, thank you.  That helped, and I will definitely use that in the future.  Many thanks!

Comment: @Ash: You don't need to loop until `$num`. If `i` becoms larger than the square root of `$num`, `$num` must be prime.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below script in which error has been removed.

**Correction:** spaces  removed `prime=$i`

```
echo "Enter a number from 10 to 100: "
read num
if (($num >= 10 && $num <= 100 ));
        then
                for ((i = 2; i <= $num; i++));do
                        if (($num % $i == 0));
                                then
                                        prime=$i
                                        break
                        fi
                done
                if (($prime == $num));
                        then
                                echo "This number is prime."
                else
                        echo "The smallest prime fatcor is: "
                        echo $prime
                fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is a `bash` programming exercise, but if it were not and [the **`factor`** util](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47185/is-there-a-practical-use-for-the-gnu-factor-command) is available, then it's as simple as:

```
spf() { factor "$@" | 
        while IFS=" :" read n f g ; do
            [ "$f" = "$n" ] && \
            echo "$f is prime." || \
            echo "The smallest factor of $n is $f." ;
        done ; }
spf 53 534
```

Output:

```
53 is prime.
The smallest factor of 534 is 2.
```

---

Since `factor` accepts input from *STDIN*, piping `spf` a list of numbers also works, *e.g.*:

```
seq 11 2 100 | spf
```